# Using VBA to create charts with data labels based on cell values

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm completely new to VBA, and would appreciate some guidance. I would like to use a macro that, on a button press, creates a chart

1. Based on the range selected by the user (shown in the image below)
2. On a new worksheet
3. With x-axis data labels being set to the top row of headings (the blue range)
4. With series labels being set according to the three group labels immediately to the left of the data. (the orange range)

[image]

So far, all I've succeeded doing is the first one, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453998/1907765), resulting in the following code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    createChart
End Sub

Sub createChart()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Selection

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=myRange

    Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Can anyone advise me how I can change this code to create the chart on a new worksheet, and using the data and series labels in a given range of cells? If need be, I can separate these into different questions. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing to do in these cases is to record a macro while doing what you just described. That will result in some code that you can put in your own code.

Comment: Probably something like `ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="{SheetName}"`

Comment: @Sam That's really helpful, I've worked out using your method how to dynamically format the axis labels, series labels and title. What I still can't work out is how to put the chart on a separate worksheet.

Comment: @Jiggles32 I tried the code you suggested, but it only works for existing sheets. I want to create a new sheet and put the chart on there.

Comment: I think `ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet` is what you want

Comment: Thanks so much, you've helped me work it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sam, I was able to work out the code I needed.

```
Sub createChart()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Selection

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=myRange

    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = Cells(myRange.Row, 2).Value
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=SheetName

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Scores!$E$1:$I$1"

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "=Scores!$C" & myRange.Row + i - 1
    Next

    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "=Scores!$A" & myRange.Row

End Sub
```

This lets me select the range, click the button, and the chart is created in a new sheet with all of the data labels I need. This should really help me out next time I need to create a chart-based macro.